# Wrong icon and label app in Huawei Phone - how to fix that?

Tags: android, icons, label, huawei-mobile-services

I got the following code to customize my app icon and label:

```
<application
    tools:replace="android:icon"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/appicon"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
```

Everything is all right, the correct icon and label show up in some phones (including brands like Samsung and Xiaomi), but when I install on a Huawei Mate 20 the result is the following image icon and label:

[image]
Do you know what I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the mobiles use round edged icon for the app icon. But other use with round app icons.Depends on the theme of the device(having a separate icon or same icon for both instances work). you should change the round app icon also :

> android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"

to

> android:roundIcon="@drawable/appicon"

and remove

> tools:replace="android:icon"

it should look like

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:icon="@drawable/appicon"
android:roundIcon="@drawable/appicon"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, bu it doesn't work...   It gave an error: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'. I can´t find the specific error btw.